# pl sql error when working with trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, database-trigger

I get an error when working with the following trigger:

```
create or replace trigger t1
  after insert or update  
     on student_tbl 
  declare
   pragma autonomous_transaction;
    begin
   if inserting then

 insert into stud_fees_details(stud_id,fees_balance,total_fees) 
       select stud_id,course_fees,course_fees from student_tbl s,courses_tbl c where s.stud_standard_id=c.course_id;

 elsif updating('stud_standard_id') then

insert into stud_fees_details(stud_id,fees_balance,total_fees) 
select stud_id,course_fees,course_fees from student_tbl s,courses_tbl c where s.stud_standard_id=c.course_id;

 end if;
end;
```

[image]

error is

> ORA-06519: active autonomous transaction detected and rolled back
>   ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.T1", line 15
>   ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SYSTEM.T1'

Comment: Removed `Sql server` and `Mysql` tag's since the error message clearly states it is `ORACLE`

Comment: Did you try searching for the error message "active autonomous transaction detected and rolled back" on a search engine? My first hit seems to explain it in a very detailed way.

Comment: Ther is the oracle [Database Error Messages](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ERRMG/toc.htm) manual that explains why this error occurs and how to avoid it.

Comment: Using an autonomous transaction in a trigger sounds like a bad idea in the first place. What is the **real** problem you are trying to solve with that?

Comment: This seems to be a so called [XY-problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY+Problem): you introduced autonomous transactions because you had another problem. Now you ask about the autonomous transaction error instead of your original problem. Besides that, is is a bad idea to create objects in the SYSTEM schema. You should create a user/schema for this purpose.

Comment: Why do you use autonomous transactions here?

Answer (score 5):

[Database Error Messages](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ERRMG/e4100.htm#ORA-06519)

> **ORA-06519**: active autonomous transaction detected and rolled back
>     **Cause**: Before returning from an autonomous PL/SQL block, all autonomous transactions started within the block must be completed (either committed or rolled back). If not, the active autonomous transaction is implicitly rolled back and this error is raised.
>   **Action**: Ensure that before returning from an autonomous PL/SQL block, any active autonomous transactions are explicitly committed or rolled back.

Example from [Database PL/SQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/static.htm#CJAICEDA)

```
-- Autonomous trigger on emp table:

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER log_sal
  BEFORE UPDATE OF salary ON emp FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO log (
    log_id,
    up_date,
    new_sal,
    old_sal
  )
  VALUES (
    :old.employee_id,
    SYSDATE,
    :new.salary,
    :old.salary
  );
  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

But @a_horse_with_no_name already stated that an autonomous transaction maybe is is not appropriate here.

After removing the autonomous transaction pragma you maybe will run into the problem that @GordonLinoff adresses with [his post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34838669/754550).

Answer (score 1):

If a trigger doesn't use `:new` or `:old`, then it is suspicious.  Your trigger is using the same table being modified in queries.

You probably intend:

```
create or replace trigger t1 after insert or update on student_tbl 
declare
   pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin
    if inserting then
        insert into stud_fees_details(stud_id, fees_balance, total_fees) 
            select stud_id, course_fees, course_fees
            from courses_tbl c
            where c.course_id = :new.stud_standard_id;

    elsif updating('stud_standard_id') then
        insert into stud_fees_details(stud_id, fees_balance, total_fees) 
            select stud_id, course_fees, course_fees
            from courses_tbl c
            where c.course_id = :new.stud_standard_id;
    end if;
    commit;
end;
```

Notes:

- The `select` statements should have table aliases, to distinguish the columns that come from `:new` and from `courses_tbl`.
- The two clauses to the `if` look the same to me, so I don't understand the logic.
- The `join` conditions between something called `course_id` and somethign called `stud_standard_id` looks suspicious.  I would advise you to name foreign keys after the primary key they refer to.

Comment: nothing in this answer will solve the problem. You trigger will raise the same error, too.

Comment: @miracle173 . . . This code should prevent the mutating table error, which is the likely cause of the failure.  This code no longer references the table being modified.  Why do you think this doesn't solve the problem?

Comment: because the problem is the autonomous transaction that is neither commited nor rolled back

Comment: @miracle173 - I'd wager that the pragma was only put there in the first place to try to avoid a mutating table error, which was only happening because of the unnecessary query against the table. I don't believe this version needs that pragma any more, or therefore the commit; but it does need to be a `for each row` trigger to reference `:new`. (It also doesn't really need the branch as both do the same thing, but that's another issue entirely).

Comment: @AlexPoole In my answer I conjectured that the autonomous transaction is  unnecessary , too. Nevertheless the reason for this error message is the autonomous transaction that is not finished correctly..

Comment: As a note for anyone reading this, the `commit` has been added.